# Python- Removing a duplicate from a string but with a twist

Tags: python-3.x

I have to create a function that removes duplicate characters from a string. There are many questions regarding this same topic, but the difference is that when removing the string, it has to evaluate if the character is equal to the one before it. For example: if the string is "teeth", the output must be "teth". The code I have now:

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
result = ""
for char in s:
    if char :
        "".join(result)
        print(char)
return result
```

If anyone can help, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
result = ""
per_char = None
for char in s:
    if per_char != char:
        result += char
    per_char = char
return result
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't working.